# trying to make a bot that counts members in a voice channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

Please don't comment if think that what I'm asking is stupid.
I am completely new to this. I tried searching up solutions but couldn't find helpful ones or ones that a noob in discord.js would understand. Thank you for your help in advance!

```js
const express = require ("express")
var app = require('express')();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello hell!")
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Project is ready")
})

let Discord = require("discord.js")
let client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => {

let newUserChannel = newVoiceState.voiceChannel

let oldUserChannel = oldVoiceState.voiceChannel

if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {

// User Joins a voice channel
console.log(client.voiceConnections.size)

} else if(newUserChannel === undefined){

// User leaves a voice channel

console.log(client.voiceConnections.size)

}

})

client.login("token")
```

repl.it
outcome when someone joins
Project is ready

```
console.log(client.voiceConnections.size)
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/VCC-Bot/index.js:30:37)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at VoiceStateUpdate.handle (/home/runner/VCC-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/VoiceStateUpdate.js:40:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as VOICE_STATE_UPDATE] (/home/runner/VCC-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/VOICE_STATE_UPDATE.js:4:35)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/VCC-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/VCC-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/VCC-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/VCC-Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `voiceConnections` is undefined. In other words, there is no object there from which to request the `size` property.  If you have a variable that can possibly be undefined, then you must test for this before using it.

Comment: how would I define it?

Comment: That question shows fundamental confusion about where stuff comes from when using an API.  I'd start by reading the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#voiceconnection).  Dunno what version you're using, but a quick search of the docs indicates that `voiceConnections` is deprecated.  Maybe that's the issue here.

Comment: the version is 12.5.1 i looked at the documentation and the new command should be guild.voice.connection; and that voiceconnection is now voicestate. cant find anything about voiceconnections.size though so I'm believing that this from the fundamentals is that right?.

Comment: From the list of changes: _"`client.voiceConnections` has been removed and is now in the `ClientVoiceManager` class. In addition, the `Collection` is no longer a getter."_  This is followed by the advice to use `client.voice.connections` instead of `client.voiceConnections` -- [(link)](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#client-voiceconnections)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! now i got an output "0" every time I join and leave. I tried joining from another alt and still 0. So, still tinkering around it. the undefined portion is the cause because it's not defining the channel it's looking at.

Comment: Okay.  Happy tinkering.  Make sure to read documentation whenever you see behavior you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i'm too late here, but you need to give the bot the intent to it.
You can add the intent like this:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES],
});
```

Comment: You should also consider to check out the documentation about the VoiceState on https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
let newUserChannel = newVoiceState.voiceChannel
```

To

```
let newUserChannel = newVoiceState.channel
```

And change

```
let oldUserChannel = oldVoiceState.voiceChannel
```

To

```
let oldUserChannel = oldVoiceState.channel
```

`client.voiceConnections` doesn't exists so, if you want this to work, try `oldUserChannel.users.size` ;)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.